# The role of major and minor numbers in device driver

Tags: linux, file-io, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am learning Linux device driver and got stuck on the **major, minor** numbers. What I have so far is:

- Devices are accessed through names in the file system. Those names
  are called as special files or device files or inodes of the file
  system.
- And each of the device files are associated with the MAJOR and MINOR numbers bundled into a `dev_t` type.
- These numbers are assigned to the device by the function `register_chrdev_region`

Some of the Questions are yet troubling me...

1. Does the `fops` structure is linked to the `f_ops` field of file structure
   of the device file when we initialize device like `cdev_init(&c_dev, &fops);`?
2. How does a call to `open("/dev/mydev", O_RONLY);` actually calls the `open()`
   function of the drivers. Does  numbers comes in picture here 
   to find the actual write method of device driver, if yes how?
3. The  numbers, major is used to identify device driver and 
   minor to device file. What is the actual role of the the this numbers
   when we perform operations on the device file like `open()` `read()` `write()` etc.?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the story should starts from what happened when you type:

```
mknod /dev/c83 c 8 3
```

it will call ext2_mknod("/dev", "c83", CHAR, DEV(8, 3)), most file systems implement mknod as a wrapper of init_special_inode:

```
void init_special_inode(struct inode *inode, umode_t mode, dev_t rdev)
{
        inode->i_mode = mode;
        if (S_ISCHR(mode)) {
                inode->i_fop = &def_chr_fops;
                inode->i_rdev = rdev;
        } else if (S_ISBLK(mode)) {
                inode->i_fop = &def_blk_fops;
                inode->i_rdev = rdev;
        } else if (S_ISFIFO(mode))
                inode->i_fop = &def_fifo_fops;
        else if (S_ISSOCK(mode))
                inode->i_fop = &bad_sock_fops;
        else
                printk(KERN_DEBUG "init_special_inode: bogus i_mode (%o)\n",
                       mode);
}
```

when you finally call open("/dev/c83"), it will goes into function def_chr_fops.chrdev_open, which will replace the fops for file "/dev/c83" with the fops your registered in cdev_init():

```
int chrdev_open(struct inode * inode, struct file * filp)
{
    struct cdev *p;
    ...
    p = inode->i_cdev;
    ...
    filp->f_op = fops_get(p->ops);
    ...
    if (filp->f_op->open) {
        lock_kernel();
        ret = filp->f_op->open(inode,filp);
        unlock_kernel();
    }
    ...
    return ret;
 }
```

after that, every system call such as read/write/close goes directly to functions pointers registered in cdev_init()!

so, for your first question:

1. yes, as you see in chrdev_open().
2. yes, since the fops of devices is really same as the one registered in cdev_init
3. plays a importance role in open(), since open() use  pairs to find the correct device drivers. but after that, other file operations, such as read/write/close(),  don't take part in again, everything goes through function pointers in fops resolved in open().